# How to manage API edit authorization IBM APIConnect Enterprise (not bluemix)

Tags: authorization, apiconnect

I am following this [blueprint](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMNED_5.0.0/com.ibm.apic.apionprem.doc/capic_syndication_using.html) to allow multiple teams in our organizations develop their own API.

I understand I can use spaces to limit the visibility on the portals. A team can only publish in his own space.

[image: Using syndication in IBM API Connect]

I don't understand how I can limit the developers on the Authoring portal, to create/edit only their own API/Products, and not API from everyone. It seems there is no such a mechanism?

How I can isolate on the Authoring side, the API from Flights team from the one from Hotels team?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no possibility of doing that. APIs are shared through all the spaces, and every API developer has access to them.

Draft APIs/Products, is an organization level permission. So every developer in an organization with this permission can view and edit every API that belongs to that organization.

In [this link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFS6T/com.ibm.apic.apionprem.doc/task_apionprem_custom_roles.html) you can see the space level permissions (which do not include any  view/edit draft api/product permission)